# Match all the characters in a regular expression untill an specific sequence or characters in order

Tags: python, regex

I want to match this text:

```
&lt;SERIES&gt;
&lt;OWNER-CIK&gt;0000003521
&lt;SERIES-ID&gt;S000020958
&lt;SERIES-NAME&gt;Alger Small Cap Focus Fund
&lt;CLASS-CONTRACT&gt;
&lt;CLASS-CONTRACT-ID&gt;C000059340
&lt;CLASS-CONTRACT-NAME&gt;Alger Small Cap Focus Fund Class I
&lt;CLASS-CONTRACT-TICKER-SYMBOL&gt;AOFIX
&lt;/CLASS-CONTRACT&gt;
&lt;CLASS-CONTRACT&gt;
&lt;CLASS-CONTRACT-ID&gt;C000095961
&lt;CLASS-CONTRACT-NAME&gt;Alger Small Cap Focus Fund Class Z
&lt;CLASS-CONTRACT-TICKER-SYMBOL&gt;AGOZX
&lt;/CLASS-CONTRACT&gt;
&lt;CLASS-CONTRACT&gt;
&lt;CLASS-CONTRACT-ID&gt;C000179520
&lt;CLASS-CONTRACT-NAME&gt;Class Y
&lt;CLASS-CONTRACT-TICKER-SYMBOL&gt;AOFYX
&lt;/CLASS-CONTRACT&gt;
&lt;/SERIES&gt;
&lt;SERIES&gt;
```

From:

```
&lt;SERIES&gt;
```

Untill

```
&lt;/SERIES&gt;
```

I'm trying with:

```
&lt;SERIES&gt;[^/]+
```

but it fails at the line with:

```
&lt;/CLASS-CONTRACT&gt;
```

[image]

If I add the S to the regex in finish even earlier since it ends with any of the character / or S appears. I need that both apear /S in that specific order

[image]

Comment: Do you want the `&lt;SERIES&gt;` and `&lt;/SERIES&gt;` to be part of the match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. It uses a lookahead so it knows when to stop.

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'&lt;SERIES&gt;.*(?=\n&lt;SERIES&)',re.S)
print(pattern.findall(text)[0])
```

output.

```
&lt;SERIES&gt;
&lt;OWNER-CIK&gt;0000003521
&lt;SERIES-ID&gt;S000020958
&lt;SERIES-NAME&gt;Alger Small Cap Focus Fund
&lt;CLASS-CONTRACT&gt;
&lt;CLASS-CONTRACT-ID&gt;C000059340
&lt;CLASS-CONTRACT-NAME&gt;Alger Small Cap Focus Fund Class I
&lt;CLASS-CONTRACT-TICKER-SYMBOL&gt;AOFIX
&lt;/CLASS-CONTRACT&gt;
&lt;CLASS-CONTRACT&gt;
&lt;CLASS-CONTRACT-ID&gt;C000095961
&lt;CLASS-CONTRACT-NAME&gt;Alger Small Cap Focus Fund Class Z
&lt;CLASS-CONTRACT-TICKER-SYMBOL&gt;AGOZX
&lt;/CLASS-CONTRACT&gt;
&lt;CLASS-CONTRACT&gt;
&lt;CLASS-CONTRACT-ID&gt;C000179520
&lt;CLASS-CONTRACT-NAME&gt;Class Y
&lt;CLASS-CONTRACT-TICKER-SYMBOL&gt;AOFYX
&lt;/CLASS-CONTRACT&gt;
&lt;/SERIES&gt;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `.*?` between the end anchors.  You'll need `re.S` so the `.` matches newlines.  The `?` makes it the shortest match, in case the ending anchor appears multiple times.

So the full string would be

```py
r"&lt;SERIES&gt;.*?&lt;/SERIES&gt;"
```

Comment: That one does not work, because of the line breaks

Comment: As I mentioned, you need to specify `re.S` so the `.` matches newlines.  If you are using a web-based tool to test your regex, it should have an option for that.